# GTAVLauncher.exe has stopped working - is there a fix?

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

I just want to play GTA V. It worked really well and I haven't had any issues with it. But since two days (AFAIK there was no patch involved between running and error times) from one day to another, it doesn't work anymore. I haven't even restarted the PC, I literally did nothing for a couple of hours and now GTA V is mad.

When double-clicking the exe files, I *immediatelly* get the error that GTAVLauncher.exe has stopped working. I can't see any user interface or anything else related to the programm. I double-click the exe and instantly get this error.

This information is given on the error:

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  BEX64
  Anwendungsname:   GTAVLauncher.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    1.0.350.1
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    5540c4df
  Fehlermodulname:  StackHash_756f
  Fehlermodulversion:   0.0.0.0
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   00000000
  Ausnahmeoffset:   PCH_A3_FROM_GTAVLauncher+0x00000000000A5B29
  Ausnahmecode: c0000005
  Ausnahmedaten:    0000000000000008
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:  756f
  Zusatzinformation 2:  756fcf3bd5e92f32a86857ffb85c6d22
  Zusatzinformation 3:  b2fc
  Zusatzinformation 4:  b2fc15a3ecd0521085a2e5533a001b35

Lesen Sie unsere Datenschutzbestimmungen online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

Wenn die Onlinedatenschutzbestimmungen nicht verfügbar sind, lesen Sie unsere Datenschutzbestimmungen offline:
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\de-DE\erofflps.txt
```

I have tried nearly every fixing guide on the interwebs, but it was worthless effort:

- the fix with disabling my graphics card doesn't work
- deleting the exe files so that they're re-downloading per PlayGTAV.exe
- disabling and deinstalling anti-virus
- compatibility mode + run as administrator
- I even created a local administrator account to launch it

**Is there a known fix for this issue?**

If you need any more information, please ask for it! I'm glad to provide it.

```
Windows 8.1 x64
i7-4790K
nVIDIA GTX 970
16 GB RAM
```

Answer (score 2):

## What does the error tell us?

```
Problemereignisname:  BEX64
Fehlermodulname:  StackHash_756f
Ausnahmeoffset:   PCH_A3_FROM_GTAVLauncher+0x00000000000A5B29
Ausnahmecode: c0000005
Ausnahmedaten:    0000000000000008
```

0xc0000005 is an exception of type (memory) [**Access Violation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), meaning that the game tried to access memory that did not belong to it <sup>[1]</sup>.  This might be a software error (bug) in the game itself, or in one of the libraries it uses <sup>[2]</sup>.

This particular error is probably raised by [DEP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483(v=ws.10).aspx) (Data Execution Prevention):

> A user-mode DEP exception results in a STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) on Windows systems. The first parameter of ExceptionInformation that is located inside the EXCEPTION_RECORD structure contains the type of access violation that occurred. A value of 8 for ExceptionInformation[0] indicates the access violation was an execution violation.

Note that this (8) is the value of your Exception Information (Ausnahmedaten).

## How do we fix this?

Because this is a **software error**, the usual course of action is to wait until the publisher updates the software.  This is the safest course to take, but may take a few days or weeks.

Another option is to [exclude this application from DEP](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-off-data-execution-prevention-dep).  However, because the DEP error is a *symptom* of the problem, and not itself the problem, there is no guarantee that adding an exception will resolve your problem.

From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention#Compatibility):

> These problems may be prevented by disabling DEP, but this increases vulnerability of the system to malware. DEP can be turned off on a per-application basis, or turned off entirely for all non-essential Windows programs and services. Microsoft recommends that DEP not be globally disabled where an application malfunctions due to incompatibility with DEP. Instead, the supplier of the offending software should be contacted for an updated version that does not violate DEP; until the problem is corrected DEP may be disabled on an exception basis for the offending application only.

---

<sup>[1] ... or that was not marked to be so accessed, e.g. trying to execute code from memory not marked as executable.</sup>

<sup>[2] However, Windows was unable to determine where exactly it went wrong, which is why it took a "Stack Hash".</sup>

Comment: Oh sorry, as a developer I also added it to DEP list. Didn't work either. Still +1 for this great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

After trying EVERYTHING, I wanted to reinstall it. I didn't had an idea why this should work (as the exe file has been redownload often), but it was from deepest desperation.

The `GTA V Installation Tool` (basically the setup) offered me a *repair function*.

*Repair functions* often caused problems a long time ago in gaming, as they have overwritten already patched files with the old ones from the physical disc.

I gave it a shot. It repaired about 5 minutes, then the launcher started. 50 MB have been downloaded and after that the most recent patch (~350 MB).

**It is now working.**

The `GTA V Installation Tool` (if a non-Steam version) can be obtain via the Rockstar Social Club website and an activated GTA V key on your account.

Comment: Hey, after logging in again I saw that my account has been hacked (see news that they saved passwords in plain text). This is even getting better!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue as of recently. It is regarding some conflicts with either programs or hardware. The community has been on Rockstar's case about this with no news as of yet. [Example.](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203452997-GTAV-Launcher-has-stopped-working-BEX64)

But there are plenty of YouTube videos regarding possible fixes for it such as [this one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7wusHwmNlM) Although you mentioned you tried disabling your graphics card already. Players have even wiped their hard drives to no avail.

Other than that there is no "offical" way of fixing it but hopefully Rockstar fixes it soon.

Comment: `the fix with disabling my graphics card doesn't work`

Comment: i stated that with a recent edit "Although you mentioned you tried disabling your Graphic Card already."